# What locale setting to use with gettext?

Tags: php, gettext

I use two seperate tutorials and have followed them carefully ([this](https://www.sitepoint.com/localizing-php-applications-1/) and [this](https://blog.udemy.com/php-gettext/)) but i still cant get gettext to translate anything. I'm on a hosted linux webserver with PHP 8.2.1 and gettext is enabled in the phpinfo.

**I can not figure out what is wrong.** Or is gettext() just not a good solution for multi-langual sites?

The po-file is this

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-03-22 14:45+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2023-01-28 12:39+0100\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: en_US\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _;gettext;gettext_noop\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 3.2.2\n"
# Test 1
msgid "SCHOOL"
msgstr "School"
```

PHP looks like this:

```
$language = "en_US.utf8";
putenv("LANG=".$language);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);
$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "Locale");
textdomain($domain);

if (!function_exists("gettext")){echo "gettext is not installed<br>";}

echo gettext("SCHOOL") . " (Works if small letters)<br>";

echo "<br><br>";
echo "Current locale: " . setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
echo "<br><br>";
var_dump(system('locale -a'));
```

Output like this:

```
SCHOOL (Works if small letters)

Current locale: en_US.utf8

C C.UTF-8 en_AG en_AG.utf8 en_AU.utf8 en_BW.utf8 en_CA.utf8 en_DK.utf8 en_GB.utf8 en_HK.utf8 en_IE.utf8 en_IL en_IL.utf8 en_IN en_IN.utf8 en_NG en_NG.utf8 en_NZ.utf8 en_PH.utf8 en_SG.utf8 en_US.utf8 en_ZA.utf8 en_ZM en_ZM.utf8 en_ZW.utf8 POSIX sv_SE.utf8 string(10) "sv_SE.utf8"
```

I used PoEdit to create the message.po file and put it in `en_US/LC_MESSAGES/message.po`

Greatful for hints on how to get it to work. Have tried and searched the web for days.
It's strange it does not work, it is a basic tutorial i follow.

Comment: Try adding this line of the 1st example, which you are missing: `bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');`.
If that does not work either, try removing the `.utf8`-part from the language, leaving it `en_US`.

Answer (score 0):

Translations are read from `.mo` files, not `.po` files. The `.po` files are just the source files for the binary `.mo` files.

The tutorials you linked explain how to create `.mo` files from `.po` files.